# Issue with camera ofset and collisions in pygame

Tags: python, camera, pygame

I'm currently trying to code a simple platform game on pygame but I have issues with the collisions when I try to add the camera functionality to the game.

Here is my code:

To don't make the question too large I'll cut the parts of the code that include the movement, the collision and the drawing.

Index.py

- removed the **init** and setup_tiles functions.

  ```
  import pygame
  from settings import *
  from tiles import *
  from player import *
  from camera import *

  pygame.init()


  class Window:

    def game_loop(self):

      while not self.crashed:

          for event in pygame.event.get():
              if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                  self.crashed = True

          self.movement()

          self.window.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
          self.all_sprites.clear(self.window, self.background)
          self.player.update(self.all_sprites)
          self.camera.update(self.player)
          self.player.draw(self.window)
          # self.all_sprites.draw(self.window)
          for sprite in self.all_sprites:
              self.window.blit(sprite.image, self.camera.apply(sprite))

          pygame.display.flip()

          self.clock.tick(60)

      quit()
      pygame.quit()

  def movement(self):
      keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

      if keys[pygame.K_w]:
          self.player.velocity_y = -3
          self.player.rect.y += self.player.velocity_y
          for sprite in self.all_sprites:
              if self.player.collide_Y(sprite):
                  self.player.rect.y = self.player.rect.y - self.player.velocity_y

      elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
          self.player.velocity_y = 3
          self.player.rect.y += self.player.velocity_y
          for sprite in self.all_sprites:
              if self.player.collide_Y(sprite):
                  self.player.rect.y = self.player.rect.y - self.player.velocity_y

      if keys[pygame.K_a]:
          self.player.velocity_x = -3
          self.player.rect.x += self.player.velocity_x
          for sprite in self.all_sprites:
              if self.player.collide_X(sprite):
                  self.player.rect.x = self.player.rect.x - self.player.velocity_x

      elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
          self.player.velocity_x = 3
          self.player.rect.x += self.player.velocity_x
          for sprite in self.all_sprites:
              if self.player.collide_X(sprite):
                  self.player.rect.x = self.player.rect.x - self.player.velocity_x

  window = Window()

  window.game_loop()
  ```

Tiles.py

```
import pygame
from settings import *

class Tiles(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, file, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.bitmap = pygame.image.load(file)
        self.bitmap = pygame.transform.scale(self.bitmap, (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
        self.image = pygame.Surface((TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE), pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.blit(self.bitmap, (0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = pos
```

Player.py

- removed the **init** function

  ```
  import pygame
  from settings import *


  class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

  def draw(self, window):
      window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

  def collide_X(self, sprite):
      if (self.rect.x + self.width >= sprite.rect.x >= self.rect.x and self.rect.y + self.height >= sprite.rect.y + TILE_SIZE >=
          self.rect.y) or (self.rect.x + self.width >= sprite.rect.x + TILE_SIZE >= self.rect.x
          and self.rect.y + self.height >= sprite.rect.y + TILE_SIZE >= self.rect.y) or (self.rect.x + self.width >= sprite.rect.x >= self.rect.x and
          sprite.rect.y + TILE_SIZE >= self.rect.y + self.height >= sprite.rect.y >= self.rect.y):
          print 'True'
          return True
      else:
          return False

  def collide_Y(self, sprite):
      if (self.rect.y + self.height + self.velocity_y >= sprite.rect.y >= self.rect.y and self.rect.x + self.width >=
          sprite.rect.x >= self.rect.x) or (self.rect.y + self.height >= sprite.rect.y + TILE_SIZE >= self.rect.y + self.velocity_y
          and self.rect.x + self.width >= sprite.rect.x >= self.rect.x):
          return True
      else:
          return False
  ```

Camera.py

```
import pygame
from settings import *


class Camera:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.camera = pygame.Rect(0, 0, width, height)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        x = - target.rect.x + int(WIDTH/2)
        y = - target.rect.y + int(HEIGHT/2)
        self.camera = pygame.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height)
```

Settings.py

```
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

TILE_SIZE = 32

LEVEL_1 = [
    'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT',
    'B                             V                       V',
    'B                             V                       V',
    'B                             V                       V',
    'B                             V                       V',
    'TTTTTTTTTB                    V                       V',
    'B                             V                       V',
    'B                             V                       V',
    'B                             V                       V',
    'B                             V                       V',
    'B                             V                       V',
    'B                             V                       V',
    'B                                                     V',
    'B                                                     V',
    'B                                                     V',
    'B              VTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTB             V',
    'B                             V                       V',
    'B                             V                       V',
    'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT'
]

LEVEL_1_WIDTH = len(LEVEL_1[0])*TILE_SIZE
LEVEL_1_HEIGHT = len(LEVEL_1)*TILE_SIZE
```

Collision without Camera

[image]

This is the collision without the camera, as you can see it works fine.

Collision with Camera

[image]

When I add the camera functionality this is what happens

If you want to test it remove the # from the game_loop and comment the drawing using the camera apply.

```
    # self.all_sprites.draw(self.window)
    for sprite in self.all_sprites:
        self.window.blit(sprite.image, self.camera.apply(sprite))
```

I'm using python 2.7 in a Window 10 x64 machine.

Comment: you use `camera.apply()` with all sprites but not with `player` - it can be problem.

Comment: BTW: it could be easier if you put complet code with images on GitHub or other portal - we could run it and test it.

Comment: It's working now, thanks @furas. I can't believe something that simple was causing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You simply are not applying the camera transform to your `player` instance: It is drawn in absolute game coordinates, while everything else is drawn in camera coordinates.

The collision checks, on the other hand, are always done in game absolute coordinates.

You have  to apply the camera to your player, before drawing it as well. As your code is, t looks like you simply have to add the player to the `all_sprites` group, and remove the Player.draw method altogether. And then, if you wish, correct something on the `Camera.update` method so that when at the border of the map, the player is not always centered on the screen.